# Read the first record from a Dexie collection including the ID

Tags: angular, indexeddb, dexie

I have a store with an auto-incremented primary key - a queue of offline posts.

```
this.version(2)
.stores({
   'offlinepost': '++'
});
```

I grab the first record with

```
table('offlinepost')
.orderBy(':id')
.first()
```

That works, but I also need to know the ID of the record to update/delete. As it is an auto-increment, it is not included in the data.

I get around it by using `.keys()` to get a separate array of keys to look up, but that seems like unnecessary work.

Is there a simple way to check a records ID that I may have missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to name your primaryKey to get it visible in objects.

[image]

so if you change to:

```
this.version(2)
.stores({
   'offlinepost': '++myPrimaryKey'
});
```

you should get the primaryKey (autoincrement) in all your objects

Comment: Thank you. I think that is the answer and I misinterpreted that bit of the manual!  I try it out in the next few days and mark you accordingly.

Comment: I revisited the code nearly three years later and realised I never tried it.  I can confirm now that ++id gives you a readable field.